# Spring Data Rest - Avoid insert in PUT Request

Tags: spring, http, spring-data-rest

When I call PUT with no id, or an inexistent one, Spring Data Rest automatically inserts the new resource.

I don't want this to happen, because I use POST for new resources; and PUT for updating them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Nothing at all. It is supposed that with the Entity & Repository, Spring creates the REST workflow.

Comment: Your desire is contrary to RFC2616: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6

Comment: Put is for updating an existing object where all not null fields need to be provided as well as the Id in the URL path. http://baseUrl/entity/{id}